# How to retrieve records for all those that don't have a specific application installed

Tags: sql

I'm using Lansweeper to deploy the CrowdStrike Windows Sensor but first I'm needing to get a list of all the machines that don't have a CrowdStrike installed. I'm creating a custom SQL report in Lansweeper to help produce my results. But my problem is I can't get those exact machines, it's only producing all other applications installed and all machines.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tblassets.assetID,
    tblassets.AssetName, 
    tblsoftwareUni.softwareName,
    tblSoftwareUni.SoftID
FROM tblAssets
    Left Join tblSoftware On tblassets.AssetID = tblSoftware.AssetID
    Left Join tblSoftwareUni on tblSoftware.softID = tblSoftwareUni.SoftID
    Left Join tblAssetCustom On tblassets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID,
    tblDomainroles
WHERE tblDomainroles.Domainrolename = 'Member workstation' 
    AND tblAssetCustom.State = 1 
    AND tblSoftwareUni.softwareName != 'CrowdStrike Windows Sensor' 
ORDER BY tblsoftwareUni.softID, tblassets.AssetName
```

This produces every application installed on every machine even if it has CrowdStrike installed or not.

I'm new to SQL, I know there's an efficient way to do this type of query, but I can't think of one. I've tried to use EXISTS but that just produces a Boolean value that then runs the outer query. I've also tried to use a subquery, but I can't wrap my head around the concept, so it isn't producing the results I was hoping for.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit joins, too confusing. Always use modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the table structures, it is a bit difficult to answer.

If you filter the tblSoftwareUni in the left join to only include 'CrowdStrike Windows Sensor', you should be able to use the where clause to only show null values in the tblSoftwareUni table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        tblassets.assetID,
        tblassets.AssetName, 
        tblsoftwareUni.softwareName,
        tblSoftwareUni.SoftID
    FROM tblAssets
        Left Join tblSoftware On tblassets.AssetID = tblSoftware.AssetID
        Left Join tblSoftwareUni on tblSoftware.softID = tblSoftwareUni.SoftID and tblSoftwareUni.softwareName = 'CrowdStrike Windows Sensor'
        Left Join tblAssetCustom On tblassets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID,
        tblDomainroles
    WHERE tblDomainroles.Domainrolename = 'Member workstation' 
        AND tblAssetCustom.State = 1 
        AND tblSoftwareUni.SoftID is null
    ORDER BY tblsoftwareUni.softID, tblassets.AssetName
```